# How do you make swiper buttons show only inside the swiper container

Tags: swiper.js

I have coded swiper button and navigation insider the swiper container but the buttons and the bullets are showing in the wrong place(at the top of the page).... I would like them to show inside the swiper container...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue when I used Swiper.
Try to use this

```
::ng-deep .swiper-pagination { `bottom: 10px;`}
```

You can modify it like you want by using some id or class for swiper.

```
<swiper class="bulletsAtBottom">some code...<swiper>
.bulletsAtbottom {bottom:10px;}
```